# Copy whole xml file in other xml in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have this xml file: http://www.studiovincent.net/list.xml

I need copy whole content in other xml file.

I tryed this code:

```
string sourcefile = "http://www.studiovincent.net/list.xml";
string destinationfile = "test.xml";
System.IO.File.Copy(sourcefile, destinationfile);
```

But not work, because I get this error: URI formats are not supported.

How Can I solve this problem?

Comment: what is the file path of text.xml have you tried copying it with a full file path

Comment: test.xml is in the application path

Comment: You cannot use `File.Copy` to copy a file from a URL, you need to use `WebClient` or something similar to download the file, and then copy it to another location (if you need to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using `WebClient.DownloadFile`. Downloading a string and then saving it could cause problems with character set mapping.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile("http://www.studiovincent.net/list.xml", "test.xml");
```

This copies the file directly rather than converting the data to a string, which might do some string conversions (for example, the file is Unicode, and `WebClient` thinks it's UTF-8) and then copying to a file.

Comment: This looks like a better solution than mine.

Comment: I tryed both solutions but xml remains empty. I dont know where is the problem.

Comment: @vincenzolopalo: I just tested that code, and it worked. Are you sure you're looking in the right place for the file? I ran it under Visual Studio in debug mode. It wrote the file `test.xml` in the bin\debug directory.

Comment: Works!! thanks, I got file in application folder!! thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

`File.Copy()` does not support the `http://` protocol, hence the `URI formats are not supported` error.

You can work around this by reading in the contents of the page into a string, and then writing it to a file.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string contents = client.DownloadString("http://www.studiovincent.net/list.xml");

// write contents to test.xml
System.IO.File.WriteAllText ("test.xml", contents);
```

*Note that `WriteAllText()` will create `test.xml` if it doesn't exist, and overwrite it if it does. You will also want to wrap the above code in a `try / catch` block and catch and handle the appropriate excpetions.*

Comment: I tryed without success, text.xml is blank. :(

Comment: Try the other answer (download file). Also, are you catching for excpetions? Go into debug mode and inspect the string to make sure it downloaded the contents.